# Incompatible type when mimicking Java hierarchy in Scala

Tags: java, scala, types

**UPDATE 15/1**: Provided a more complex example using custom classes in type parameters

I'm trying to provide a Scala interface for an existing Java interface. In the java side, you have the following hierarchy:

```
interface JavaBuffer
interface JavaStreamBase
interface JavaReadStream<T> extends JavaStreamBase 
interface JavaTimeoutStream extends JavaReadStream<JavaBuffer>
```

In the Scala version, I'm trying to provide a similar structure to make it familiar, and one of the requirements is that you need to be able to get the Java version at any stage in the hierarchy. So, I had something like this:

```
trait ScalaBuffer {
  def asJava: JavaBuffer 
}
trait ScalaStreamBase {
  def asJava: JavaStreamBase
}
trait ScalaReadStream[T] extends ScalaStreamBase {
  def asJava: JavaReadStream[T]
}
class ScalaTimeoutStream(val asJava: JavaTimeoutStream) 
  extends ScalaReadStream[ScalaBuffer]
```

The scala code fails to compile with this error:

```
Error:(22, 25) overriding method asJava in trait ScalaReadStream of type => JavaReadStream[ScalaBuffer];
 value asJava has incompatible type
class ScalaTimeoutStream(val asJava: JavaTimeoutStream)
                    ^
```

The problem here is that `JavaTimeoutStream` is a `JavaReadStream<JavaBuffer>`, and in Scala I'm trying to force `JavaReadStream[ScalaBuffer]` to be the same, and that does not work.

One way to solve this is to have two type parameters in ScalaReadStream trait, e.g.

```
trait ScalaReadStream[T, J] extends ScalaStreamBase {
  def asJava: JavaReadStream[J]
}
class ScalaTimeoutStream(val asJava: JavaTimeoutStream) 
    extends ScalaReadStream[ScalaBuffer, JavaBuffer]
```

However, this sucks and complicates the types unnecessarily IMO.

Would path dependent types help better here? Any other solutions?

Thanks a lot for any help in advance!

p.s. This is a small example but no, I don't want to use the Java interfaces in the Scala code since in reality the Java classes are littered with Java class references, Java collections...etc.

p.s.2. I know I could alternatively use implicit conversions instead of trying to mimic the Java hierarchy, but doing so would add extra complexity for users coming from Java since they'd not have a hierarchy that matches what happens in Scala. If I have no other choice or the hierarchy structure becomes too complicated to deal with this edged case, I might go down that route.

Comment: The option with `java.lang.Long` works, so your problem is solved. Though it seems you should provide example for the unsolved problem. (Is there a reason you cannot use the Java interfaces directly in Scala?)

Comment: Update the problem description to address your concerns.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I do not know how the path dependent types would help here without a further type parameter (which you rejected as making things too complex). I am sorry to not being able to give better help. I would go with the implicit conversions. The type classes would give a nice and clean solution for this imho.